# Kafka connect worker missing AbstractConfig and AvroConverterConfig classes

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I am trying to use a kafka connect JDBC sink connector with avro. But when i try to start the connector i keep getting the two following errors :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroConverterConfig

and

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/common/config/AbstractConfig.

I am a little but confused here because my plugin path is /app/confluent-5.0.0/share/java

[confluent-5.0.0/share/java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrgWL.png)

And we can see the jar corresponding to the missing class is there.

Anyone has an idea about what is causing this missing class ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: It looks like you have both 5.0 and 5.4 jars present... How did that happen? Have you considered using Docker instead?

Comment: Plugins don't find classes. Your CLASSPATH does

Comment: oups thats a mistake a tried to add the 5.4 jar to see if it was only the version 5.0.0 that wasn't working ! i removed it. and i am using docker. I pulled the entire confluent-5.0.0 and start the worker with the script.

Comment: and you said plugins dont find classes but classpath does .. from what i understood setting the plugin.path to /share/java is loading all the jars from there to the classpath right ?

Comment: in fact i am able to run a lot of different connectors, but as soon as i use avro, i get some class not found exception

Comment: No. Plugins are only certain connectors/transforns, not all classes. Have you tried https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.3.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml

Comment: no i didn't yet , but how do you load classes to the classpath if its not with the plugin.path worker attributes ?

Comment: we can see it is not loaded in jvm.classpath but as a plugins

Comment: Because the script that starts the connect server knows where to look for the classpath variable https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka/blob/master/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L169

Comment: 2020-02-17 14:12:41,132 INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed) [main]
2020-02-17 14:12:41,332 INFO Loading plugin from: /app/confluent-5.0.0/share/java/confluent-common (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]

Comment: What about it? Again, this isn't a Confluent issue. Any NoClassDefFoundError from any Java process means that the CLASSPATH is misconfigured. Either wrong, or JARs are missing.

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason you can't use like 5.0.2 or even latest 5.3.x?

Comment: ok i get that my classpath is misconfigured but how do i configure it since im using confluent script to start my worker ?

Comment: It would be useful if you could edit your question to include what you've downloaded. You say you're using Docker, but if so, what variables are set on your containers? You say you have "started the worker with the script", what script? Do you already have the classpath variable already defined elsewhere in your environment variables? And what's stopping you from trying other Confluent versions?

Comment: nothing is stopping me from trying other version but i just wanted to know what was not working with this one. and for the scripts, i have a custom script initializing the env variable and at the end im calling

Comment: exec $SCRIPTS/connect_distributed.sh /tmp/temp.properties

which is the original script from confluent

Answer (score 0):

basically i have just pulled the binaries for confluent-5.0.0 from confluent, i have a custom script getting the env variable and setting them to the worker variables like that :

if [ "$1" = 'bash' ]; then
    exec "$@"
else
  if [ -z "$KAFKA_CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS" ]; then
    export KAFKA_CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="kafka:9092"
  fi

if [ -z "$KAFKA_CONNECT_GROUP_ID" ]; then
    export KAFKA_CONNECT_GROUP_ID="connect-cluster"
  fi

and then calling at the end :

exec $SCRIPTS/connect_distributed.sh /tmp/temp.properties

Comment: Which base image are you using? Why did you edit the entrypoint?